# Simple Web Audio API example plays in JsFiddle but not locally

Tags: javascript, audio, web-audio-api

I have found a simple example of the web audio API in action here:
http://jsfiddle.net/stuartmemo/xMruN/

When I run it in JsFiddle it works perfect (in Chrome) but when I copy the code locally it doesn't work. Here is the code I've used locally:

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Test</title>

<script type="text/javascript">
var context = new webkitAudioContext(),
oscillator = context.createOscillator();
oscillator.type = 3;
oscillator.frequency.value = 500;
oscillator.connect(context.destination);
oscillator.noteOn(0);​
</script>
```

I feel like this has a simple solution I'm overlooking but I've been at it for 20 minutes.
BTW I'm running my local example on a web server (even though I doubt I should have to).

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should wait for window to load like so:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    var context, oscillator;
    try {
        context = new webkitAudioContext();
    } catch (e) {
        alert("Your browser does not support Web Audio API");
    }
    oscillator = context.createOscillator();
    oscillator.type = 3;
    oscillator.frequency.value = 500;
    oscillator.connect(context.destination);
    oscillator.noteOn(0); // play it immediately
    oscillator.noteOff(1); // turn it off after 1 second from now
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Removed this line and it works.

`oscillator.noteOn(0);`​

Answer (score 0):

> Removed this line and it works.

```
oscillator.noteOn(0);​
```

The noteOn method is deprecated in the Web Audio API. You can change that line to:

```
oscillator.start(0);
```

… and it should work as originally intended.

> BTW I'm running my local example on a web server (even though
>   I doubt I should have to).

Actually, some of the Web Audio API stuff won’t work unless you run it from a server. So you are doing the right thing by running a local server.

Answer (score 0):

Oscillator types are no longer specified with integers. Use strings instead, e.g.

`oscillator.type = 'sawtooth';`

I don't know if that is what's causing your problem here. Perhaps JsFiddle used an older implementation of the web audio api?